# Fetching esJsonRDD from elasticsearch with complex filtering in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am currently fetching the `elasticsearch` RDD in our `Spark Job` filtering based on one-line elastic query as such (example):

```
val elasticRdds = sparkContext.esJsonRDD(esIndex, s"?default_operator=AND&q=director.name:DAVID + \n movie.name:SEVEN")
```

Now if our search query becomes complex like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "default_operator": "AND",
                    "query": "director.name:DAVID + \n movie.name:SEVEN"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "movieStatus.boxoffice.status",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "movieStatus.boxoffice.status.rating": "A"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "movieStatus.boxoffice.status.oscar": "false"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I still convert that query to in-line elastic query to use it with **esJsonRDD**? Or is there anyway that the above query could still be used **as is** with **esJsonRDD**?
If not, what is the better way to fetch such RDDs in Spark?

Because esJsonRDD seems to accept only inline(one line) elastic queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple quotes:

```
val query = """{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "query": "director.name:DAVID + \n movie.name:SEVEN"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "movieStatus.boxoffice.status",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "movieStatus.boxoffice.status.rating": "A"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "movieStatus.boxoffice.status.oscar": "false"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}"""

val elasticRdds = sparkContext.esJsonRDD(esIndex, query)
```