# Spark Jobs errored out with : Too many elements to create a power set 34

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, scalability

Am trying to run a spark job in mesos cluster querying elastic data, using the esJsonRDD querying something like this:
[Fetching esJsonRDD from elasticsearch with complex filtering in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527299/fetching-esjsonrdd-from-elasticsearch-with-complex-filtering-in-spark/44528004#44528004)
, and ran fine for the multi-node elastic cluster with less than 32 nodes. As the nodes in the elastic increased, the jobs are failing with below exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Too many elements to create a power set 37
```

as mentioned in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/737

Am using elastic `2.3.4`, is there any workaround for the same version of elastic?
Here are my gradle dependencies of my current Spark Job.

```
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.0.0'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '2.3.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the `elasticsearch-spark` version to `5.5.0` as mentioned in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/737 and it worked.

```
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11', version: '5.5.0'
```